# Difference between command line runas and right click Run As

Tags: windows, command-line, runas

I want to run an application (.exe file)  with a specific user while i'm logged in with another user.
The application which I'm invoking is a licensed one and hence can executed by a specific user.

I refereed this post https://superuser.com/questions/105913/run-as-for-a-bat-file and tried 2 different options as suggested by users i.e. using the command line runas command and using Run As from the context menu.
However for me the context menu one worked but not the command line so there is definitely some difference between the two.
How to make the command line runas work same as context menu Run As ?

I tried following command

`runas /profile /env /user:MYUSER "Path to my batch file"`

Comment: On my machine, there is no "run as" context menu item.  Is this something you have installed or enabled on your machine, or did you mean "run as administrator" ?

Comment: I followed some of the answers on https://superuser.com/questions/105913/run-as-for-a-bat-file and was able to get that option. You need to do registry changes to get that option.

Answer (score 0):

`runas /user:<localmachinename_or_domainname>\username path_to_bat`
Should be all you need.
As a test, try making your bat file to just run "set" and output to a file, so you can verify that you in fact ran it under that user.
also, in your batch (bat) file, you need to treat it like another DOS prompt.
If your just starting a program, just use
`start "c:\pathtoprogram.exe"`
For my test example you would enter
`cmd /c set>C:\test.txt`